# Regular expression: multiple subdomain in email address

Tags: java, regex, email, extract

It wasn't hard to find everything between the `@` character, but the problem is that I need every word before the `.`(dot) character.

If the email, for example, is: `studentname@student.studentschool.com`, then I need to have the every word after the `@` character and before every `.`(dot).

```
student  
studentschool
```

What I tried so far only works for one domain.

```
(?<=@)[A-Za-z]{2,40}
```

Can't figure it out.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Find Content after `@` with `String#substring` and split with `.` with the help of `String#split`. Why are you using regExp for this ?

Comment: what @TAsk says is clearly the best approach for this simple requirement as it will be infinitely faster than a regex

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I know that it's not the best solution but I need to use regex for a school assignment. That's the reason why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy! Try this:

```
([^.@]+)\.
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/nM4jV7/2

### Explanation:

Get everything that's just before a dot, but doesn't consist `@`. Then capture the string in a group, excluding the ending dot.

Comment: I do not think it is a good style to start each answer with `Easy!`. It might not be easy for everyone. BTW, `(?2)` is not supported by Java regex.

Comment: Didn't mean anything harsh. It is just to give them optimism. I didn't mean to demean anybody. It depends on how people read it.

Comment: Hmmm, java is kind of annoying in term of regex. Other language is starting to replace Java bit by bit.